# How to Add an Object Inside Another List Object

Tags: java, list

I have an object class A, and a list object for class B

```
A a = a.findById(aId);
List<B> b = b.findById(bId);
```

Class `B` has `A` class

```
public class B {
   private int id;
   private A a;
   ...getters setters
}
```

Is it possible to add object `a` in object list `b`?

I get error when I try to add `a` in object list. 
`b.add(a);` This tells me to change object `a` as `B a...`

How can I add object `a` in the list object `b`?

Comment: No, a banana can't be added to a list of apples. Simply because a banana is not an apple.

Answer (score 0):

You can add object `a` if you wrap it in object `B`. Otherwise, you will not be able to add object `a` of type `A` to `List<B>` of `B` objects because of the type mismatch: you are trying to add object of type `A` to the list of `B` objects which is not allowed in Java.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add object `a` in object list `b`?

Simply, no because they're not the same types.

> How can I add object a in the list object b?

in order to add both instances of class `A` and class `B` into one collection, one approach you can take is to make an interface in which both class `A` and class `B` implement.

**Example:**

```
public interface ISomeInterface {
    // define some methods in which both class `A` and `B` share 
}
```

Then make the classes implement the `ISomeInterface` interface:

```
public class A implements ISomeInterface {

}

public class B implements ISomeInterface {
    private int id;
    private A a;
}
```

then you can do something like this:

```
List<ISomeInterface> b = new ArrayList<>();
b.add(new A());
b.add(new B());
// note you can only call methods through which the interface defines
// another solution is to cast the types, that way you can invoke the methods that belong to each type
// make use of instanceof keyword to prevent exception
```

or simply without the need of making interfaces:

```
List<Object> b = new ArrayList<>();
b.add(new A());  //if you want to call the methods of A or B you need to cast it first, remember to use instanceof keyword prior to casting
b.add(new B());
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to add a A to B would be first get B, then add A to B, such as

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

b.add(A);
```

if you wish to add both to the same `List<>` then they need to implement the same or inherit from the same class, example interface `IAB`

```
List<IAB> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new A());
list.add(new B());
```

given that

```
public interface IAB{}
public class A implements IAB{}
public class B implements IAB();
```

note that in this case you can only call the methods that are available on the Interface unless you cast it to the class (but if you mix A and B that might be complicated to handle)